# Extjs4 set a button at the very left side of a statusbar

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have a statusbar where I want to set a button at the very left side of it. I can place it left using margin but it does not set completely at left side. But I need to do it. Can anyone please help me on this ?! Here is my code below :

```
me.tbar = Ext.create('Ext.ux.StatusBar', {
        id: 'showgridtbar',
        tooltip: 'Print Payment Details',
        topBorder:false,
        items: [
          {xtype: 'button', iconCls: 'printp', margin: '0 0 0 -90', tooltip: 'Print Payment Details'}
        ],
    }),
```

Comment: Add tags like Javascript like **relevant popular tag** too. It attracts more users

Comment: Why are you using a StatusBar as the top bar? isn't better to use a Toolbar there? What are your requirements? What is the class in wich the bar resides, a simple Panel? A Window? The StatusBar simply aligns items at right because it adds a text control to show the messages and, everything else is aligned to the right, it has a filler after the text.

Comment: @VoidMain tbar works. thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is quite easy, you need to use `statusAlign: 'right'` like so

```
bbar: Ext.create('Ext.ux.StatusBar', {
     statusAlign: 'right', // the magic config
     items: [{
            text: 'A Button'
     }, '-', 'Plain Text', ' ', ' ']
})
```

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sran/czrt6/29/)**